# Why analysis of variance should I use for my clinical trial proposal?

Tags: anova, manova

I have 2 independent variabiles(2 treatment groups) and 2 outcomes, measured at 3 time points. Is manova the analysis I should use?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It sounds like you may want a [repeated measures MANOVA](https://statistics.laerd.com/spss-tutorials/one-way-repeated-measures-manova-using-spss-statistics.php) test.

You correctly noted that you want a a MANOVA test, rather than ANOVA. This is because ANOVA is appropriate when you have a single outcome variable. You have 2, which necessitates MANOVA.

With 3 measurements you want a repeated measures test.Repeated measures tests for differences between the different measures ("between subjects effects").

You say that you have two treatment groups as two independent variables. I'm imagining this looks something like "Received Treatment A (Yes/No)" and "Received Treatment B (Yes/No)". If that's correct, you are moving into a mixed-model MANOVA in which you have both within-subject and between-subject effects.

Comment: Thank you ! Could I analyze the effect on each dependent seperately or just jointly ?

Comment: @iic If you thought this answer was helpful please consider upvoting it. Also think about accepting the answer if it solves your problem. The general "workflow" for a MANOVA is that it will detect whether any significant relationship exists between one of the independent variables and one of the dependent variables, but it doesn't tell you which ones. Your second step will be to use ANOVAs to figure out which ones are important.